# Can I use client credentials grant type to login on default login page of Spring Auth Server

Tags: spring-authorization-server

I have been trying to implement Spring OAuth and while doing so am  able to generate token via client creds grant type as well. I was hoping to use the default login page for logging in clients instead of users, but am unable to find the document for the same. I would be thankful if anyone can guide me to the right document for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can do that, since the Client Credentials Flow (defined in OAuth 2.0 [RFC 6749, section 4.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)) involves an application exchanging its application credentials, such as client ID and client secret, for an access token.

As stated [here](https://auth0.com/docs/get-started/authentication-and-authorization-flow/client-credentials-flow), this flow is best suited for machine-to-machine applications, such as CLIs, daemons, or backend services, because the system must authenticate and authorize the application instead of a user, so in this case it would not be necessary to display a login page.

Also, as explained [here](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/), the Client Credentials grant is used when applications request an access token to access their own resources, not on behalf of a user.

I hope that these 3 mentioned documentations will help you to better understand the client credentials flow mechanism!